# Is the continuation monad and the imperative monad talking about the same thing?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm looking at this post http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2373

and they talk about continuations and imperative monads. I can't figure out what the difference is between the two. Are they the same thing?

Comment: can you quote where you see "imperative monads"?

Comment: They talk about imperative 'constucts' which I assumed to be some sort of monad. http://lambda-diode.com/programming/monads-are-a-class-of-hard-drugs. It would be good to get a better idea of what they are

Comment: "constructs" is just a general term for some piece of the language, like a for loop in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Continuations

Consider a diagram of two functions, F calling G, passing it a value of type A and getting a value of type B back:

```
F       G
|
V
A------>A
        |
        |
        V
B<------B
|
```

It is kind of a view of stack over time, if you want to consider the implementation using stacks. Looking at it this way is important for understanding computation time as effect - function F is kind of "waiting" for G to complete. (Or you could see this as a exchange of messages in pi-calculus, where obviously F is blocked until it receives a message from G.)

Now, suppose, after F got the result back, it did some more computation, returned to the caller, etc, eventually the caller called F again, and again, ...:

```
F       G
|
V
A------>A
        |
        |
        V
B<------B
|
...
|
V
A------>A
        |
        |
        V
B<------B
|
...
|
V
A------>A
        |
        |
        V
B<------B
|
```

Hang on, but this is the same as swapping F and G on the lines:

```
G       F
        |
        V
A<------A
|
...
|
V
B------>B
        |
        |
        V
A<------A
|
...
|
V
B------>B
        |
        |
        V
A<------A
|
```

If the previous diagrams showed F calling G to compute B, then this last diagram looks like G calls F to compute A from B. So, who's calling who?

This dualism is captured by the notion of continuation: function F can be represented in two ways; one of the ways is the way you want to write it, the other way represents F as a continuation of F, a view of F from G's standpoint. This latter view of F is like writing F from the return point of G, where B is available. This of course requires re-writing G differently, because instead of "returning" to F it must call continuation of F, expecting another A, and be "ready" to produce another B. Also, this means that the whole program is re-written, too, because now F instead of "returning" to the caller will have to call the caller's continuation, etc.

So far we only looked at the case where F calls G again and again. But how will the case where F only calls G once look? Well, from G's standpoint continuation of F will look like a **non-terminating** computation.

In order to keep G general, that is, to enable calling G from other functions, too, it is usually re-written to accept an extra argument, the continuation function. So, "F calls G" means F passes A and a continuation of F to G ("H calls G" means H passes A and a continuation of H to G, etc). This transformation is what is understood by "continuation-passing transform".

The return point on the stack in stack-based implementations of function calls *is* the continuation the caller passes to the function being called - so, continuation passing is no different from stack-based function calls, just making the passing (and "invocation") of return point explicit.

### Continuation monad

Continuation monad captures **computation time as effect** - instead of assuming B will be immediately available to F, we can write G in such a way that it calls F's continuation when B becomes available. At the same time, calling F's continuation does not assume A will be immediately available to G, so G's continuation will be called when A becomes available, etc.

"Time as effect" pops up in many other guises - in Iteratee, Partiality monad, Codensity monad...

Comment: Thanks Sassa. Do continuation monads always use Cps?

Comment: @zcaudate I don't think I understand the question. Continuation passing is a equivalent representation of the program. Continuation Passing Transform is the method of converting the program. Continuation Monad captures the notion of continuation and continuation passing.

Answer (score 4):

The article doesn't talk about imperative monads - it talks about "an imperative mind", and about imperative languages. The word "imperative" is being used to represent a general style of programming, not a particular technical construct.

In general monads, along with the associated "do-notation" in Haskell, give you a way to structure a program in an imperative style, with the code expressed as a sequence of actions.

Some monads can probably be seen as more imperative in nature than others - for example the state monad explicitly expresses the concept of a state that can be updated by each action, whereas the list monad is much more about non-determinism.

The continuation monad is one specific monad. It's quite a general one and also relatively hard to understand initially. If I were classifying monads by "imperativeness" I would put it somewhere in the middle.

Comment: wow! Interesting way to put it. Can you elaborate in what sense the list monad is about non-determinism?

Comment: A value of type `a -> [b]` can be considered as a non-deterministic computation which takes an `a` and yields a `b` from a list of zero or more possible values.  The `>>=` instance for `[]` represents composing these non-deterministic computations.

Comment: @SassaNF - It's most obvious when using comprehensions or `do`-notation: consider `do x <- [3,4,5::Int]; y <- [6,7,8]; return (x,y)`

Comment: @TomEllis Oh, I see. "Non-determinism" as in "not a one-to-one map".

Comment: @SassaNF: Right, specifically a one-to-zero-or-more map, (where ordering is also preserved, in the case of the list monad).